# Serialize datetime.datetime object as JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7, datetime, object, encode

Currently working on a quick little project in python and am attempting to encode an object into a JSON string. I've done this several times before without any problem except for now. Usually I just do the following.

```py
def ClassToEncode :
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argn) :
        self.attr1 = arg1
        self.attr2 = arg2
        ...
        self.attrn = argn

     ...
     def toJSON(self) :
         return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

But the problem is that one of my class attributes is a datetime.datetime object and I am being thrown the following error

```
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Any thoughts or wraparounds that could enable the functionality of including the datetime attribute into the JSON output??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) method on a datetime object to convert it to an ISO-8601-formatted time string, then serialize it as JSON just fine. On the other end, call [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) on the formatted string to convert it back into a `datetime` object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> now = dt.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 4, 3, 19, 44, 214096)
>>> isonow = now.isoformat()
>>> isonow
'2014-09-04T03:19:44.214096'
>>> fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"
>>> newtime = dt.strptime(isonow, fmt)
>>> newtime
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 4, 3, 19, 44, 214096)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to modify your toJSON() method to use a customized dictionary in which you customize the data:

```
import datetime

def ClassToEncode :
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ..., argn) :
        self.attr1 = arg1
        self.attr2 = arg2
        ...
        self.attrn = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

     ...
     def customDict(self):
        dup = self.__dict__.copy()
        # configure dup to contain fields that you want to send
        dup['attrn'] = self.createdAt.isoformat() # datetime object
        del dup['attr2'] # Some private field you may want to hide
        return dup
     def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.customDict())
```

Answer (score -1):

While the accepted answer works great. If you don't need any date formatting you could quickly get away with direct string conversion.

So something like below should work

```
str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

json.dumps should be able to serialize this string now.